# GROUP BY on view queries

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.5.16

I'm writing a query which contains several aggregate columns and many ungrouped columns. I've condensed the core logic.

```
SELECT min(table_b.aggregate_column),
table_a1_key,
table_a2_key,
table_a1_column
FROM api.view_a
JOIN api.table_b USING (table_a2_column)
GROUP BY table_a1_key, table_a2_key;
```

`view_a` joins `table_a1` and `table_a2` and exposes `table_a1.table_a1_key` + `table_a2.table_a2_key`. But I get this error when executing:

```
ERROR:  column "view_a.table_a1_column" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Am I required to include other columns in the GROUP BY clause, even though they are functionally dependent on my grouped columns?

From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions **or when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns**, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. **A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column**.

Comment: The phrase you citate means that when the mentioned conditions are not observed the result can be not deterministic. And that such field in a grouping expression is excess (removing this field formally will not affect on the result) formally only. But it do not mean that you can skip such field in the grouping expression - because the standard exists. It is allowed in some DBMS (MySQL, for example), but it is a local SQL extension. Postgres have no such extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that `table_a1_column` is functionally dependent on the other columns, but PostgreSQL isn't smart enough to deduce that.

If `view_a` were a regular table, PostgreSQL would know that the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause contain the primary key, but since it is hidden behind the query rewrite rule of a view, it cannot infer that.

For PostgreSQL there are no functional dependencies between the columns of a view. It might be technically possible to improve that, but it is doubtful whether that would be worth the extra effort during query planning, particularly since the query can be fixed by simply adding all columns to the `GROUP BY` clause.