# PostgreSQL group by with just primary key is allowed on tables but why not views?

Tags: postgresql, view

Using PostgreSQL 11.18

It's possible to select rows from a table with a group by that only includes the primary key even if all of the columns appear in the select clause:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  id int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,
  column2 int,
  column3 int
); 

SELECT id, column2, SUM(column3)
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY id;
```

That's because column2 has a functional dependency on id so it does not need to be included and column3 is used as a parameter to an aggregate function.

If you instead replace querying against the table with a view that's simply a select of all of the columns in the table:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS 
  SELECT id, column2, column3
    FROM table1;

SELECT id, column2, SUM(column3)
  FROM view1
 GROUP BY id;
```

It'll fail with:

```
ERROR:  column "view1.column2" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT id, column2,  SUM(column3)
                   ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 12
```

So if you're replacing direct access to tables with views and there's code that omits the additional columns in the group by - it'll fail.  Why is this?  Is this a bug or does the notion of a primary not apply to views?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [GROUP BY on view queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238087/group-by-on-view-queries) found by a coworker.